# How can we read array from one file to another file without name of the array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i hava file called test.php,in this file I have array like this :

```
array(
  [0] => $x_axis_t1 = "1,2,3,4,5";
  [1] => $y_axis_t1 = "1,2,4,3,2";
  [2] => $x_axis_t2 = "1,22,73,49,5";
  [3] => $y_axis_t2 = "1,9,8,2,1"; 
)
```

This array I need to call or read in another file called test2.php, is there any way to read the array, if it is possible could please explain.

Note:in test.php file array has no name.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a valid format to store an array as a text file. Try using JSON or serialising a php array.

Comment: the array format is not valid - once you have a valid array format you could `require()` or `include()` `test.php` in `test2.php` to access the array.

Comment: thanks for your response @jibsteroos your correct bt this array i did write from codeigniter controller using fwrite($fp, print_r($trace, TRUE)); into test.php file,I got that array ,so is there any way to write an array with name into the file .Thanks

Comment: You may be better off writing the data as something like json - so `file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($trace));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clearly you just have to include test.php in test2.php

```
//In test2.php you have:
<?php
    include 'test.php';
```

The above will make array accessible in test2.php

Meanwhile, I doubt that array is valid I believe you are better off storing it as variables or better still give the array a name with indexes reflecting the variable names above.

What are you trying to do precisely?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize` or `json_encode` PHP functions to serialize the array data and then store in a file as plain text, like below:

```
$data = array(
           [0] => "1,2,3,4,5",
           [0] => "1,2,4,3,2",
           [0] => "1,22,73,49,5",
           [0] => "1,9,8,2,1",
);

$data = serialize( $data );

file_put_contents( 'test.php' , $data );
```

The above will store the array in test.php file in serialized form. The next is to read this data to some variable of your choice.

```
$new_data = file_get_contents( 'test.php' );
$new_array = unserialize( $new_data );
```

`$new_array` now has the array data loaded from the external file. Hope this solves the problem.